# How can I pass a variable from one PS script to another via VBS?

Tags: winforms, powershell, vbscript

I am working on a PowerShell script with a GUI with 3 files:

- `window1.ps1` - input into variable and starts `start.vbs`
- `start.vbs` - starts `window2.ps1`
- `window2.ps1` - displays the value entered in window1

In window1, I enter `value1` into `textbox1` and click the `button`.

[image: gui window 1]

By clicking it, `value1` should be stored into a `global variable`, so that `window2` can pop up (via VBS) and use `value1`.

**code for `button` in `window1`:**

```
$button_OnClick= 
{
    $global:value1 = $textBox1.Text
    start-process .\start.vbs
}
```

**start.vbs:**

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.run("powershell.exe -nologo -file .\window2.ps1"), 0, True
```

So far so good. From what I understand, `value1` is a global variable and can be used in `window2.ps1`.

So `window2` is an empty window with only a text that should display `value1`.

```
$label1.Text = "$value1"
```

But for some reason, the variable is empty and `window2` is empty.

[image: gui window 2]

What am I missing? I'm still learning PowerShell and I might be missing a detail.

> note: I know the way I open up `window2` via .vbs is weird. But that
>   way, the GUI opens up without any PowerShell window in the background.

Comment: The VBS detour to get a windowless Powershell process is not terribly uncommon. See the lower part of my answer for a generalized approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "global variable" is not something that is magically available to every process all over your computer. You're starting two completely separate PowerShell processes. None of their stuff is shared.

You need to give the value as a command line argument to the second PowerShell process if you want to use it there.

And that means you have to give the value your first PowerShell script generates as a command line argument to your intermediary VBScript, because that's a completely separate process, too.

The first PowerShell script calls wscript.exe with two arguments (script name and value):

```ps1
$button_OnClick= 
{
    $value1 = $textBox1.Text
    Start-Process wscript.exe "window2.vbs","`"$value1`""
}
```

Assuming the user has entered `Hello World!`, this will execute the command line (note the quotes, they make sure that values with spaces are not seen as separate arguments):

```
wscript.exe window2.vbs "Hello World!"
```

The VBS intermediary can then read `Hello World!` from it first command line argument (the quotes will have been stripped, so we need to add them back for the next call):

```vb
value1 = WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.run("powershell.exe -nologo -file .\window2.ps1 """ & value1 & """"), 0, True
```

now the following command line is executed:

```
powershell.exe -nologo -file .\window2.ps1 "Hello World!"
```

The second PowerShell script can then pull `Hello World!` from its first command line argument, just as the VBScript did (the quotes will have been stripped again):

```ps1
$label1.Text = $args[0]
```

---

I would recommend that you make a VBScript `windowless.vbs` that can run just about any command windowlessly:

```vb
' windowless.vbs
For Each arg In WScript.Arguments
    If InStr(arg, " ") > 0 Then
        cmd = cmd & """" & arg & """ "
    Else
        cmd = cmd & arg & " "
    End If
Next
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(Trim(cmd)), 0, True
```

and then use it in your PowerShell script

```ps1
$value1 = "Hello World!"
Start-Process wscript.exe "windowless.vbs","powershell.exe","-nologo","-file window2.ps1","`"$value1`""
```

which would create this command line

```
powershell.exe -nologo -file .\window2.ps1 "Hello World!"
```

which is exactly what we need here, and it can be reused easily for other cases.

Comment: thank you for that answer! That makes a lot of sense. I copied your code and there are no errors now but window2 is still empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say. Add a `MsgBox(value1)` to your VBScript and see what it gets. Also, have you seen the lower part of my answer?

Comment: yes, I have seen the lower part and added it. The msgBox works and displays value1. That means that calling the argument in the second script is the problem.

Comment: @gwynbleidd Ahh, it has to be `$args[0]`, not `args[0]`, in the second script. Typo on my end.

Comment: didn't work either. $args is empty. Is there maybe a mistake in the part of the .vbs where we pass the argument?

Comment: I tried first fixing the VBS with the aditional " as you mentioned, but window2 is still empty (msgbox in vbs works thought) with the second method you wrote, window2 is empty aswell. :(

Comment: @gwynbleidd Well, what can I say. I tested the entire chain more than one time now and it works. If it does not work for you, you're doing something different. Try to call your second script manually on the command line. Compare your manual call with what the VBScript does.

Comment: just rewrote everything again, works now. Thank you a lot for everything!

Comment: Will this work for shell objects? or only with strings?

Comment: @xXAngelJinXx Command lines are strings, there is no way to pass an object this way.